# Conflict between navigation drawer and right side menu

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer, slidingmenu, android-sliding

I need your help. I make my first steps in android programming!

**SOS!!!**

I created classic navigation drawer which you can open/close by clicking of hamburger icon or sliding from left side. I also created right side menu (like in Facebook app) and used this library from GitHub (https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu). At the end i had **conflict between Drawer Navigation Menu and Right Side Menu**.

When Navigation Drawer Menu opened and you want to close it by sliding from right to left opened right side menu.

So **my question**: How to said to device that when navigation drawer menu is open you can`t open right side menu by sliding and by sliding you can just close navigation drawer.

My **code of right side menu** in MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
menu.setMenu(R.layout.sidemenu);
menu.setBehindWidthRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_behind_width);

String[] items = {"Fisrt fragment","Second fragment"};
((ListView) findViewById(R.id.sidemenu)).setAdapter(
        new ArrayAdapter<Object>(
                this,
                R.layout.sidemenu_item,
                R.id.text,
                items
        )
);
```

**NavigationDrawer code:**

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME="testpref";
public static final String KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER="user_learned_drawer";

private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;

private View containerView;

public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mUserLearnedDrawer = Boolean.valueOf(readFromPreferences(getActivity(),KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER,"false"));
    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
        mFromSavedInstanceState=true;
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
}

public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar){
    containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(),drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if(!mUserLearnedDrawer){
                mUserLearnedDrawer=true;
                saveToPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, mUserLearnedDrawer+"");
            }
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);

            if(slideOffset<0.6) {
                toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset);
            }
        }
    };
    if(!mUserLearnedDrawer&&!mFromSavedInstanceState){
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(containerView);
    }
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

}
public static void saveToPreferences(Context context,String preferenceName, String preferenceValue){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(preferenceName, preferenceValue);
    editor.apply();
}
public static String readFromPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String defaultValue){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
    return  sharedPreferences.getString(preferenceName, defaultValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another level, like this: http://pastebin.com/xm8UZbvj

Comment: But here is just interface. I need logic solution.

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: Not, because I don't use the sliding menu

Answer (score 0):

when user try to open right menu then check if navigation  drawer is open then close it by using below code-

```
if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)){
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

Comment: so as i understand if users want to open right side menu first they need to close Navigation Drawer. i created my nav drawer with ActionBarDrawerToggle. In this your code what mean mDrawerList?! I have error in mDrawerList. Sorry for such stupid questions. I am just beginner.

Comment: if you are using navigation drawer then you should have a listview which you use in your navigation drawer.So you have to pass object of that list view.

Comment: as a matter of fact i want to use GridView elements in my navigation drawer, but anyhow i added private ListView mDrawerList; so now there is no mistake in code but app don`t want to open in emulator. I don`t understand what to do now. Can you look to the code above which i added to the post. Code of NavigationDrawer. I added what you said to it. Please i need your professional view. I will wait your soon answer.